# UK tourist Visa Refused

Tags: visas, uk

We applied for a tourist VISA for 5 people,  who are Me,  My Mother,  My Father,  My Brother's close friend and a cousin of mine. Me and my parents got the VISA.  However,  My brother's friend's and my cousin's got refused.  The purpose of us visiting the UK is to meet my brother (non resident)  and sister in law (British Resident) and to attend their blessings ceremony in the UK. We attached the sponsorship  letter, pay slips and invitation from my brother and sister in law. I want to ask, should we reapply for my brother's friend?  As you can see in the refusal letter its mentioned that the business provisional registration is of 26/6/17, which is true but its because GST got introduced in INDIA in june'17. He has his business registration documents which are 9 months old as he started his business at that time.  The other concern is income tax return,  as he is new into the business or work,  he was not aware of the tax submission earlier,  and then he was waiting for the GST to be introduced,  so that he can file the ITR correctly. Another consern is his bank statement not matching with his income stated, is because he has other savings which he got after his father passed away in june 2015. He has his mother and 2 sisters to take care of in INDIA. His mother has the source of income from the interest of fixed deposits worth INR 25,00,000 and the rent which she recieves from the property which his father owned and after his father's death it got transferred in the name of his mother and himself.  He is the owner of the house in which he stays with his family.  This house was gifted by his father to himself, when he was alive.  Me and my brother's friend are in a relationship from last 8 year and are soon planning to get married. He has clear intention to return to India as hismother and sister are depebt on him,  not financially but because of his mother's health conditions. We also missed mentioning his family's dependancy on him and abouf the bank balance which he got after his father's demise.  Request you to suggest what should we do?  As I never thought of visinting the UK without my boyfriend. Should we reapply?  Are there any chances of getting VISA if reapply?  Is it that if they refuse to give VISA to my boyfriend twice, the possibility of him getting VISA in the future gets minimal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually (some of) the reason(s) are there. They cite paragraphs V4.2(a) and V4.2(c), so check https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e. Also you should edit the picture(s) you upload so they don't reveal personal information.

Comment: Thanks Henrik.  I want to know that if there is a change to get the visa if I provide additional documents and mention the details which I missed mentioning previously?